# How long is the time of the transfer of the reputation value from the main to the meta site?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta, meta-reputation

It seems to be more than half an hour? Does it vary?

Comment: The time of the transfer of the reputation value from the main to the meta site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to
[FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation):

> Reputation here is entirely derived from the main website; your reputation is the same here as it is there, **synchronized hourly**. Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way. However, you can earn unique badges here on the meta site.

I've learned about this from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89634) on meta.SO.

**EDIT**: It seems that the above link to faq has been changed in the meantime. The same information is now contained in [What is "meta"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 1):

at least 50 min! At least recently.

Comment: I think it is not in minutes as much as a timed process, sat every hour, on the hour. Something like this...